# Hover li not covering the entire li - css

Tags: html, css

As in the CSS below, when I run the project and hover over the `li` the color only affects the background of the text and not the entire li row.

But when I change the code to the below it covers the entire row.

```
.items-results li:hover {
     background-color: #000;
 }
```

How is this happening ?

```css
.items-html--menu:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items-results" id="item-results">
  <li class="items-html--menu">HTML</li>
  <li class="items-html--menu">CSS</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: because the dot is part of the ul tag not the li tag.

Answer (score 0):

The dot isn't part of the LI, so you'd have to remove the list style and use a pseudo element (ie: before)

```css
.items-html--menu {
  list-style: none;
}

.items-html--menu:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.items-html--menu:before {
  content: "\2022";
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items-results" id="item-results">
  <li class="items-html--menu">HTML</li>
  <li class="items-html--menu">CSS</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think what is being asked is that Why the dot is not highlighting when style is added through the <ul> , while the dot is highlighting when same style is added through the <li> element.

Comment: In his code he hasn't styled the UL so I assume he means the LI itself?

Comment: @faiz-e maybe the bullets of the `ul` are disregarded while parsing the separate `li` elements because of performance/speed issues. @Paul RoboPHP mentions the `ul` in the css.

Comment: @Paul yes, he want to highlight the `li`. He has done it already. All he wants to know is why it isn't highlighting when done like `.items-results li:hover` :)

Comment: @retterBadach Yes, maybe.